# Hiding command prompt in wxpython app

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, wxpython, py2exe

I have written a gui application using wxpython and converted it into an executable using py2exe. However whenever I run the executable, the command prompt comes up in the background and closes when i exit the program. Is there any way to not make it appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propply set the application type to `console` in py2exe setup:

```
setup(console=...
```

while you need to make it `windows`:

```
setup(windows=...
```

Here I have a simple wxpython application in a file named `example.pyw`:

```
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-
#!python

# @file: example.pyw

import wx

class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, title, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AppFrame, self).__init__(None, title=title, *args, **kwargs)
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)


class AppMain(wx.App):
  def OnInit(self):
    self.frame = AppFrame("Example")
    self.frame.Show()
    return True


AppMain(True).MainLoop()
```

this is a simple setup in a file named `setup.py`:

```
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-
#!python

# @file: setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
RT_MANIFEST = 24

# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly
manifest = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
    />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
      version="9.0.21022.8"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"
      language="*"
    />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
"""

setup(
  windows = [{
    "script" : "example.pyw",
    # "icon_resources" : [(1, "icon.ico")] # have an icon?
    "other_resources" : [(RT_MANIFEST, 1, manifest)]
  }]
)
```

put them in the same directory and `cd` to that directory and run `python setup.py py2exe`:

```
> python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
creating C:\Users\XXX\build
creating C:\Users\XXX\build\bdist.win32
...
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
   MSVCP90.dll - C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\MSVCP90.dll
   RPCRT4.dll - C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
>
```

if everything went well, you should have a folder named `dist` with `example.exe` inside. Run it and it should show the window without the console.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the newer versions of wx require the SxS manifest any more. I was thinking that was only in Python 2.6 and wx 2.8

Comment: Sweet!! Much appreciated. I had to comment out the "other_resources" line though. Was showing me a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in cmd.