# How do i stop the command prompt window from opening when i run my python program?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, py2exe

I don't want the cmd window opening in the background when my python app is opened. Why does this happen and how can i make it so when my program is opened only the GUI is showing not the command prompt as well.

Edit - I used tkinter for my GUI and i have made it into a .exe i converted it to .exe via py2exe.

Comment: Did you create an executable?

Comment: Note that the concept of a "dos window" does not exist any more.

Comment: What GUI (tkinter, wxPython, glade, ...)? How are you running the app? On what OS?

Comment: I used tkinter for my GUI and yes i created and .exe !

Comment: Did you use py2exe or pyinstaller?

Comment: i used py2exe to convert it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6480595/3001761

Answer (score 3):

You probably set the application type to console in py2exe setup:

`setup(console=...`

while you need to make it `windows`:

`setup(windows=...`

You can check this answer: [Hiding command prompt in wxpython app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151463/hiding-command-prompt-in-wxpython-app)